# How does kafka and schema registry share KafkaProperties? ('basic.auth.user.info' was supplied but isn't a known config.)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I still cannot wrap my head around how is kafka producers / consumers *and* schema registry intended to reuse `KafkaProperties`. Or is it not intended to reuse same structures?

so for schema registry, I have to configure for example following properties:

- spring.kafka.basic.auth.credentials.source
- spring.kafka.basic.auth.user.info
- spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url
- spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema.registry.url

but if I do so, and call `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties#buildConsumerProperties`

and proceed with build hashmap I will get for example warning:

`The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.`

I saw recommendation to set schema registry urls as such, I also saw setting `basic.auth…` like this. I really cannot get it working. I mean the app is working, I just get several pages of these warnings. I'd like to know how to configure the app correctly, as it was intended by design, so that I can share 1 configuration for confluent kafka and schema-registry configuration

Sure I can get separate configuration of properties "to be added" for schema registry, or bend it somehow, so that I can build separate set of properties for both, but it just don't feel right, this clearly isn't how it was (I hope) designed. What is the correct procedure here? Maybe it's hidden somewhere in depth of autoconfiguration, but if its there I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question on Gitter earlier today; it comes up a lot:

https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-kafka?at=60d490459cf3171730f0d2d4

> It's rather unfortunate that Kafka supports configuring (de)serializers via the producer/consumer configs, but then emits these annoying (ignorable) log messages.

If it bothers you, I suggest you open a JIRA against the `kafka-clients`.

Comment: setting the configuration through yml won't take only the required parameters? please see my answer

Comment: No; you will still get the warning; all Boot does is set the producer properties.

Comment: There is a separate configure method for Serializer and Deserializer interfaces. This seems more like it could be handled better by Spring-Kafka to me

Comment: When you use properties, Kafka creates and configures them, not Spring. You can configure them as beans and pass them into the consumer and producer factories via setters or constructors instead, if you choose.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks for your answer, I wanted to know if I'm doing something wrong. Seems that I'm not. It is not about what bothers me, but I need to see project green, and these huge amount of warnings and problems can hide real issues. Just avro generates 2 pages of warnings in 1.9.2 in "we don't care" manner. Ok then, I will stick to my solution, to have configuration with N named KafkaProperties, and will decompose it further to be able to configure data only for schema registry within given configuration.